# How to set background color to $actionsheet in ionic frameworks

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework

Here is the code, very simple and copy paste from office website

```
$scope.show = function() {
        // Show the action sheet
        var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
            destructiveText: 'Delete Photo',
            titleText: 'Modify your album',
            cancelText: 'Cancel <i class="icon ion-no-smoking"></i>',
            cancel: function() {
                // add cancel code..
            },
            buttonClicked: function(index) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        // For example's sake, hide the sheet after two seconds
        $timeout(function() {
        hideSheet();
        }, 2000);
    };
```

[image]

I want to change the cancel button have a red color background, how I can achieve it in ionic frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to look at the markup using your browser (after running ionic serve in your terminal), for example in Chrome ctrl+shift+i, where you can choose the button and see what classes are attached.  In your case you'll see something like this:

```
<div class="action-sheet-group action-sheet-cancel" ng-if="cancelText">
    <button class="button ng-binding" 
            ng-click="cancel()" 
            ng-bind-html="cancelText">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Which has styles that for the parent div, and child button something like this:

```
.action-sheet-group {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.action-sheet .button {
  display: block;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #d1d3d6;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #007aff;
  font-size: 21px;
}
```

Just change these values either in Sass or directly in your styles sheet if you're not using Sass.